# Add custom button next to native "Apply" button in the edit-tag screen

Tags: admin, buttons

I am aware that a button can be added next to the WordPress native "Filter" button using the `restrict_manage_posts` filter. An example is shown in the screen below.

[image: Screenshot 1]

However.. Is there any way (filter or action would be great), to add a similar button to the edit-tags screen, i.e. the main taxonomies list screen? Screenshot of where I would like the button to go is below.

[image]

I performed a rather extensive search and I cannot find anything for this..

Thanks for your time.